# Some applications can't play/pause/skip in the gnome panel - Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 (both LTS)

Tags: 20.04, gnome, 22.04, gnome-flashback

When I open Spotify on Firefox I can control the streaming by clicking on the speaker icon on the top bar. I'm using gnome Flashback.

[image: Working on Firefox]

But if I use the Spotify app or open it on Google Chrome, it doesn't work, although it shows the last used app :

[image: Not working on Chrome]

On firefox it works for other sites, like youtube.

Firefox is an external installation via PPA.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Are The Spotify app and google chrome installed via snap? AFAIK gnome integration(themes, controls and etc) is mostly broken as of now.

Comment: Spotify was installed via snap, Google Chrome was a .deb file downloaded from Google and installed via dpkg -i.

Comment: Try using the .deb version. There is a minor glitch in Spotify's website. once you go to the download page, Click on the download button on the top black bar, and follow the instructions.

Comment: Try reinstalling chrome again and see if it works.

Comment: For Spotify the .deb version worked, but for Chrome it didn't (.deb download from Google)

Comment: I would recommend porting your google chrome data over to firefox, as firefox is much more efficient than chrome.  Plus you also get More privacy features as a bonus. But if you still want chrome, then AFAIK that chrome doesn't have this feature.(as I have seen in my laptop)